# OpenCV cvCloneImage cause bad argument error: file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp

Tags: opencv

I have a very simple code trying to copy an image from another:

```
IplImage* image = NULL;
IplImage* imageDraw = NULL;

image = cvLoadImage(argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
imageDraw = cvCloneImage(image);
```

I pass the image file name from command line. Without imageDraw = cvCloneImage(image); it all runs fine. With cvCloneImage, it compiled fine, until runtime it gives an error: 
bad argument  in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp

My opencv version is 2.4.5

My question is how to solve this

Comment: Could make sure image is correctly loaded before you call `cvCloneImage`? For example, test `if (image != NULL)` and maybe print out the number of columns and rows of `image`. BTW, it would be better if you could use the C++ interface.

Comment: I just tested, and you are right, image is NULL... Now the problem becomes why cvLoadImage is not loading correctly. I have .jpg file in the local folder, it shouldn't have problem of finding the file

Comment: Maybe show us how you call the executable? And your folder structure? Adding `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` may helps debugging as well.

Comment: okay, I solved it, it is a folder structure issue. Thanks alot for help

Comment: If you start OpenCV now, better get used to cv::Mat. IplImage is obsolete and complex for high-level programming.